# Deleting an app with the status "Developer Rejected"

Tags: ipad, app-store-connect

Is there a way to delete a version of an app with the state "Developer Rejected"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just looking to delete the rejected version (and not the entire app), there is no way to do that. When you upload a new binary, this will override and replace the rejected binary.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're wanting to do is release a new version number and not use the old version number. You can do that by changing the version number within the version RECORD that had the rejection.

1. In App Connect, go to the version that was rejected.
2. Scroll down to the "Version" field.
3. Enter the new version number that you want it to be.
4. In the Build section, remove the rejected build, and add the newer build that should replace it.

The old version number is gone, as if it were deleted.

Comment: this one should be the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot delete just the rejected version. Once you reject the binary you can click the "Ready to Upload Binary" button to start again

Also note that if you don't fill out the "App Review Information" the "Ready to Upload Binary" button will not appear.

In my case, the binary was already approved and had the status of "Pending Developer Release"
Due to bug fixes I wanted to reject the approved binary and submit another for review.
After filling out the app review information section and refreshing, the button appeared and I was able to upload the new binary for review.

I know this is an older post but I figured to put this here since it took me a while to get the "Ready to Upload Binary" button to appear. I didn't want to submit another answer, but I didn't see an option to just add a comment to the accepted answer.